# 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' error while sending mail in django

Tags: python, django, django-email

I got this error while sending email.

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
            messages.info(request,'Username taken')
            return redirect('registration')
        elif User.objects.filter(email = email).exists(): 
            messages.info(request,'Email id is already registered')
            return redirect('registration') 
        else:    
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password= password, email= email, first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name)         
            user.save()
            auth_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
            print('done')
            print(auth_token , email)
            send_mail_after_registration(auth_token , email)
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user=user , auth_token = auth_token )
            profile_obj.save()
            
            return render(request, 'token_check.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

def send_mail_after_registration(ctoken , email):
   
    print("hiii")
    subject = 'Your account need to verified- MyTrip'
    message = 'Hello, \n We are excited to have you get started. First, you need to confirm your account. Just press the Link below. \n  Or paste the link in browser to verify `your account http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/'+ctoken + '\n \n If you have any questions, just reply to this email—we are always happy to help out. \n Cheers, \n The MyTrip Team'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    print("hii")
    #msg=EmailMessage(subject,message,to=recipient_list)
    #msg.send()
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
```

Error description:

```
AttributeError at /registration/

'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/

Django Version: 3.2.6

Exception Type: AttributeError

Exception Value:    
'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Exception Location: c:\users\prachi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\smtplib.py, line 647, in auth

Python Executable:  C:\Users\prachi\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe

Python Version: 3.9.5

Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\prachi\\projects\\travele2',
 'c:\\users\\prachi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\prachi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\prachi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\prachi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\prachi\\Envs\\test',
 'C:\\Users\\prachi\\Envs\\test\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 26 Aug 2021 07:41:41 +0000
```

In this, error location shows in file which is built in. It was working fine at first but when I run this after a month, it gives me this error.

Comment: Can you please paste the send_mail function as well? Probably the issues should be in the types of variables used in sendmail function.

Comment: Check your settings.py file for the value you have set of settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER as the other arguments you are passing into send_mail we can see and are correct so it's likely that this is set  to an integer rather than a string.  Also check what you have settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL set as, this settings entry allows you to set the default email address. If you so that, and it's the address you are sending from, you do not need to pass in the from_email argument

Comment: You have set settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER to a valid string value?